# Delete not working and redirecting to the same page - Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and was facing a problem. I have made a delete function in Controller and added it in the route properly. Then I connected it to a button in the view. When I press the button, it redirects me to the same page without deleting anything.

Here's my function :

```
 public function delete_user($id){
        $data = User::where('id' , $id);
        $data->delete();
        return route('home');
    }
```

Here's my route :

```
Route::get('/delete/user/{id}' , 'UserController@delete_user');
```

I am adding it in view like this :

```
 <a href="{{action('UserController@delete_user' , $user->id)}}"><button class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right">Delete Profile</button></a>
```

After redirecting there is a ? infront of the url like `abcd.com/delete/1?`

When I hover over the button, it shows the correct route(bottom left corner in image), but nothing is happening when I press it : [image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

EDIT : The same function works perfectly fine in another view instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation it seems that I made a rather careless mistake. I was deleting as a form submit type. I just took the button outside the form and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public function delete_user($id){
    $data = User::where('id' , $id)->first();
    // or
    // $data = User::find($id);

    $data->delete();

    return route('home');
}
```

Whenever you use the `where` clause to retrieve a single resource you have to call `first()` or `get()` for a collection.

Try doing it this way:

Controller method

```
public function delete_user($id){

    $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    $user->delete();

    return route('home');
}
```

Route

```
Route::delete('/delete/user/{id}' , 'UserController@delete_user')->name('delete-user');
```

View

```
<a class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right" href="{{ route('delete-user') }}"
    onclick="event.preventDefault();
         document.getElementById('delete-user').submit();">
    {{ __('Delete user') }}
</a>

<form id="delete-user" action="{{ route('delete-user') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
   @csrf
</form>
```

Also I think  `<a href="{{action('UserController@delete_user' , $user->id)}}"><button class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right">Delete Profile</button></a>` should be problematic because you have a button inside a link...its wrong. If you want to use button the the approach I just showed you is better. but really your link should look like:

```
 <a href="{{ url("/delete/user/{$user->id}")}}">Delete Profile</a>
```

Comment: it just redirects to the same link with a ? infornt i.e `abcd.com/delete/1?` from  `abcd.com/delete/1`

Answer (score 1):

you need to modify your delete function inside controller like below...

```
public function delete_user($id){
        $data = User::find($id);
        $data->delete();
        return redirect('/home'); //write name of view where you want to go.
    }
```

Comment: `User::where('id' , $id)` will not do much, missing a `->first()`. Or simply use `User::find($id)`

Comment: Thanks @kerbh0lz

Comment: It does not work, it just redirects to the same link with a ? infornt i.e `abcd.com/delete/1?` from  `abcd.com/delete/1`